# Люди не-книги и люди книги

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография

Вычитываю рукопись, автор пишет: "людей делили на две группы: людей не книги и людей книги". Признаться, у меня легкий ступор. Как оформить, нужны ли кавычки, нужен ли дефис в выражении "люди не-книги"? Где-то встречалось такое написание. А может, вообще ничего не менять?
Один из ключевых моментов: как я понимаю, имеются в виду не люди, которые как книги ("человек-оркестр"), а люди, которые "привержены" книге (как "человек слова").

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется безнадёжной попытка составить понятие *люди* "не книги" (тем более, "не-люди-книги"). Можно предложить автору отойти от этой формы и назвать их напр. "людьми книги" (книжными - если важно совпадение по форме) и "*людьми не книжными*". Иначе возникает недоразумение: "люди-не-книги" похоже на протестное отрицание тождественности людей книгам, а "не-люди-книги" напоминает о "нелюдях".

Comment: Разделяю ваше мнение насчет безнадежности формулировки. Такое предложение вообще не должно было на свет появляться) Его, в идеале, почти полностью нужно переиначить. "Книжные люди" - ведь тоже тот еще оборот.

Comment: Я на всякий случай при первом упоминании предложил оформление: _люди "не книги"_ (кавычки ввиду крайней условности, а раздельно, поскольку отдельное понятие "некнига" здесь не подразумевается).

Comment: Попробуйте использовать два термина: "люди книги" и "те, кто к ним не относится"

Comment: У Кобо Абе есть известный роман "человек-ящик". Из названия следует, что есть и "люди-неящики" (орфографию пока вынесем за скобки). Следовательно, ***автор делит облей на две категории: "люди-ящики" и "люди-неящики"*** Какие проблемы, почему такое предложение не должно появляться в реальном тексте?!

Comment: Это совсем другой случай: "человек-ящик" имеет противоположность "человек-неящик". Здесь же речь не идёт о слове "человек-книга (человек-некнига)"; как я понимаю, "человек книги" - это что в духе "человека дождя", а не "человека-паука".

Answer (score 1):

Здесь без какого-то компромисса не обойтись. Проблема - в разном отношении к грамматической одушевленности, что приводит к разной парадигме для винительного падежа.

Оставим пока просто "люди-книги" (тут дефис сомнений не вызывает) и попробуем просто найти винительный падеж. Он как минимум несвободен. Это не уникальный случай, "человек-оркестр", например, порождает те же сложности в винительном падеже. А вот "человек-книга" склоняется без проблем.

Но есть выход. Давайте рассматривать это "люди-книги" как **название** категории. В именительном падеже все получается.

Дальше. "Некниги" в данном случае вполне можно (а скорее всего и нужно) писать слитно. Это не отрицание, а новое понятие. И это тоже нам на руку. 
Опуская лишние пояснения, имеем.

***"людей делили на две группы: люди-книги и люди-некниги"***

Берете?

> нужен ли дефис в выражении "люди не-книги"

Здесь в таком оформлении нет нужды (если принимаете мой вариант). Могу что-то такое представить, когда автор сомневается, в каком качестве он видит объект (некниги), т. е. отрицание тут или новое понятие. А видеть вы могли нечто подобное в изданиях до 1956 г., а то и вовсе дореволюционных, по другой орфографии написанных. Но и там это объяснялось скорее не просто орфографическими затруднениями автора, а особенностями стиля.

Comment: *Здесь без какого компромисса не обойтись.* "Без какого-**то**"?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Неудобно было писать. Да там не только это... Сейчас поправлю с нормального компьютера. Всё, теперь можете проверять. )))

Comment: Действительно, много, тоже читал и не заметил.)

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы не даёте разгуляться авторской фантазии? Мне кажется, если переиначить оборот, он потеряет изюминку. А сказано, действительно, необычно: люди "не книги" и люди "книги". Если поставить тире между словами, значение изменится.

Comment: *Если поставить тире между словами, значение изменится.* Вы опять путаете тире с дефисом. Или Вы хотите сказать, что и дефис тут не годится?

Comment: Нет, Артём, я говорю именно о тире между подлежащим и сказуемым (имею в виду  слова "люди" и "книги"). Речь шла о тире между ними. Ваши уроки я усвоила.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что Пряничек говорила о дефисе, а тире она и не предлагала ставить.

Comment: *Если поставить тире между словами, значение изменится.* - уточните, всё же, это гипотетическое тире - между какими словами и в каком выражении?  В нашей фразе в сочетании "люди-книги" нет подлежащего и сказуемого, это приложения.  В целом я согласна, авторский стиль тут вполне приемлем и попытка кардинально перестроить всю фразу - не самая удачная идея. Но вопрос орфографии (и пунктуации) не снимается.

Comment: Сейчас, IrinaGL, попробую объяснить. Вы решили, что это простое  предложение с обобщающим словом ДВЕ ГРУППЫ, а далее идут однородные члены с приложениями, обособленными дефисом. Объясняется, какие именно это группы. ЛЮДИ  какие?  КНИГИ (т.е.приверженные, преданные книге). А я решила, что это сложная конструкция, где первое предложение простое, затем идёт бессоюзная связь, и два простых распространяют содержание первого.. Два нераспространённых односоставных предложения: люди - книги, люди не книги; (то есть люди сравниваются с книгами, возможно, они ими являются). Вот, как говорят, как-то так.